# Triangle is not shown in a PyGame window

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, pygame, pyopengl

I want to print out a triangle on the computer screen.I am using the `PyGame` library for the window the `OpenGL` library for rendering of the screen.

I have this code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy as np
import ctypes
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileProgram,compileShader


class Shape:
    def __init__(self,vertices:tuple,counter:int):
        self.shapeid:int = len(vertices)/6
        self.vertices = np.array(vertices,dtype=np.float32)
        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(counter)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        self.vbo = glGenBuffers(counter)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.vertices.nbytes,self.vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,24,ctypes.c_void_p(0))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,24,ctypes.c_void_p(12))


class Window:
    shapes:list[Shape] = []

    def __init__(self,width:int,height:int):
        display = (width,height)
        pg.display.set_mode(display,DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
        glClearColor(1.0,0.0,0.0,1)
        self.shader = self.createShader("Shaders/vertex.txt","Shaders/fragment.txt")
        glUseProgram(self.shader)

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type==pg.QUIT:
                    pg.quit()
                    quit()

            glUseProgram(self.shader)

            for i in self.shapes:
                glBindVertexArray(i.vao)
                glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,0,3)

    def createShader(self,vertexShederFileName:str,fragmentShederFileName:str):
        with open(vertexShederFileName,'r') as v:
            vertex_src = v.readlines()

        with open(fragmentShederFileName,'r') as f:
            fragment_src = f.readlines()

        shader = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_src,GL_VERTEX_SHADER),compileShader(fragment_src,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
        return shader

    def addShape(self,shape:Shape):
        self.shapes  = self.shapes + [shape]


pg.init()
win = Window(720,360)

triangle = (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,
            1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,
            0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
            )

shape2 = Shape(triangle,1)
win.addShape(shape2)
win.loop()
```

and the shaders are available from the answer of one my last question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77428974/22864242

So lets analyze the code a little bit:

In the `Shape` class I just create the VertexBufferObject and the VertexArrayBufferObject then I bind them.

In the `Window` class the display is initialized from the `PyGame` library then we initialize the shader for the rendering of the Window and what was expectable is the screen to print out a triangle.

Lets take a closer look on the triangle:It is made of 18 points which is correct since stride = 6 and 18/6 = 3.The color of the triangle should be white because I set the last 3 floating numbers to `(1.0,1.0,1.0)` which is the RGB value of `(255,255,255)`.So I dont see any reason why it shouldnt print out a white triangle.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using the wrong [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type. Use `GL_LINE_LOOP` instead of `GL_LINES`.
2. The display needs to be updated with [`pygame.dispaly.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
3. As the scene is redrawn in every frame, you should also clear the display before drawing.

```py
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            quit()

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glUseProgram(self.shader)
    for i in self.shapes:
        glBindVertexArray(i.vao)
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 3)

    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: @Root No you are wrong [`GL_LINE_LOOP`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives) exists in all OpenGL versions.

Comment: I cant find it.

Comment: @Root Click on it, it's a link. I'm not a beginner, I've been doing this for ages and I know what I'm talking about.