# Drawing rectangle analysis

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, pygame

I decided to print out a rectangle on the screen of a `PyGame` window.In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77429576/22864242) I asked how to draw a Triangle and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77429669/22864242) helped me actually print out a triangle.

I tried to do the same for a rectangle so lets dive in the analysis:

The `Shape` class shouldnt change since:

```
class Shape:



    def __init__(self,vertices:tuple,counter:int):

        self.shapeid:int = len(vertices)/6

        self.vertices = np.array(vertices,dtype=np.float32)



        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(counter)

        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

        self.vbo = glGenBuffers(counter)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.vbo)

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.vertices.nbytes,self.vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,24,ctypes.c_void_p(0))

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

        glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,24,ctypes.c_void_p(12))
```

a rectangle is still a list of vertices and the structure of each vertex shouldnt change since it is still specified by the same 6 floating type numbers `(x,y,z,r,g,b)`.

So any changes should be made in the `Window` class:

```
class Window:

    shapes:list[Shape] = []

    def __init__(self,width:int,height:int):

        display = (width,height)

        pg.display.set_mode(display,DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

        glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1)

        self.shader = self.createShader("Shaders/vertex.txt","Shaders/fragment.txt")

        glUseProgram(self.shader)



    def loop(self):

        while True:

            for event in pg.event.get():

                if event.type==pg.QUIT:

                    pg.quit()

                    quit()



            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

            for i in self.shapes:

                glBindVertexArray(i.vao)

                if i.shapeid==3:

                    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3)

                elif i.shapeid==4:

                    glDrawArrays(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,0,4)







            pg.display.flip()















    def createShader(self,vertexShederFileName:str,fragmentShederFileName:str):

        with open(vertexShederFileName,'r') as v:

            vertex_src = v.readlines()


        with open(fragmentShederFileName,'r') as f:

            fragment_src = f.readlines()

        shader = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_src,GL_VERTEX_SHADER),compileShader(fragment_src,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

        return shader


    def addShape(self,shape:Shape):

        self.shapes  = self.shapes + [shape]
```

Since now we have 4 vertices we have set the 3rd parameter of `glDrawArrays()` =4.I checked out if there was a issue with the number of elements in the `rectangle`

```
pg.init()

win = Window(720,360)






rectangle = (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,

        0.0,0.5,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,

        0.5,0.5,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,

        0.5,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0

        )

shape1 = Shape(rectangle,1)



win.addShape(shape1)

win.loop()
```

since if for example `len(rectangle)`=23 then `self.shapeid:int = len(vertices)/6` returns 3 and obviously the code doesnt work but I think the elements of `rectange` are 24 so I dont know why this code doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE` cannot be used with [`glDrawArrays`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml). This enum constant has no meaning in connection with `glDrawArrays` and causes an OpenGL error ([`glGetError`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml)).
The valid primitive types are `GL_POINTS`, `GL_LINE_STRIP`, `GL_LINE_LOOP`, `GL_LINES`, `GL_LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY`, `GL_LINES_ADJACENCY`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP_ADJACENCY`, `GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENCY`, `GL_PATCHES` and the deprecated (still avalaibel with a compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context)) `GL_QUADS` `GL_QUAD_STRIP`, and `GL_POLYGON`.

So if you want to draw a rectangle you have 4 options:

1. Use a compatibility OpenGL Context and `GL_QUADS`
2. Draw 1 singe rectangle with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` or `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`
3. Stick the rectangles together with 2 triangles and 6 vertices
4. Use an index buffer and [`glDrawElements`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) and Stick the rectangles together with 2 triangles and 4 vertices